# I am getting TypeError:"int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Question'"

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am getting error when I try to fetch Question object from my Choice object.
The error is : int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Question'

I have two Models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField("date published")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text


class Choice(models.Model):
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question,  related_name='choices', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Here is my view :

```
@api_view(['POST', ])
def selectChoice(request):
    try:
        choice_id = request.query_params.get('choice_id')
        selected_choice = get_object_or_404(Choice, id=choice_id)
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        questions = get_object_or_404(Question, id=selected_choice.question)
        serializer = QuestionWithAnswer(questions)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    except ValueError as e:
        return Response(e.args[0], status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Here is my Serializer:

```
class ChoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ('id', 'votes', 'choice_text','question')


class QuestionWithAnswer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choices = ChoiceSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('id', 'question_text', 'pub_date','choices')
```

And I expect below API response:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "question_text": "What's your age?",
    "pub_date": "2019-04-13T05:27:39Z",
    "choices": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "votes": 15,
            "choice_text": "15",
            "question": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "votes": 2,
            "choice_text": "16",
            "question": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "votes": 2,
            "choice_text": "17",
            "question": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: please share the full stack trace. And what is `QuestionWithAnswer`?

Comment: I have edited my question, please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do that `get_object_with_404` call. `selected_choice.question` is *already* the relevant Question object, it's not an ID. You can pass that directly to the serializer.

```
serializer = QuestionWithAnswer(selected_choice.question)
```

Comment: As I mentioned in above comment, this solution is also working.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an object on your queryset instead of an id. Your queryset should look like this:

```
questions = get_object_or_404(Question, id=selected_choice.question.id)
```

Comment: Thanks.This is working like a charm.I will upvote the answer once I have enough credit.Please can you explain a bit in detail as I am new to python?

Comment: But this is the *wrong* answer. As I point out, the whole call is useless.

Comment: It's giving me the output I required.Even Your answer is working and but please any of you can explain the difference and which is better?

Comment: Queryset-wise, this is correct @DanielRoseman. However, your solution might suit better the case. Anyhow, Simal, you were basically trying to query the DB by "filtering" by an ID and passing a queryset object instead of an id. Have a look here to better understanding. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404